# Is there any function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which is $C^1$ and has an invertible derivative matrix at all points, but is not 1-1?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which is $C^1$ and has an invertible derivative matrix at all points, but is not 1-1?

Thanks!

Comment: The condition $\| F(u)-F(v)\| \geq c\|u -v\|$ (with $c > 0$) already proves $F$ is $1-1$ without any assumptions about being $C^1$ or having invertible derivative.  To see this, assume $F$ is a (set theoretic) function satisfying $F(u) = F(v)$.  Then $0 = \| F(u) - F(v)\| \geq c\|u-v\|$ which implies $\|u-v\| = 0$, so $u=v$.

Comment: True, that part of my question was irrelevant so I removed it. I was getting confused, you could use that condition + C1 to show that the function is actually onto, which is a more substantial argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $F(x,y)=(e^x\cos y,e^x\sin y)=(u,v)$. Then $F(x,y)=F(x,y+2\,\pi)$, so that $F$ is not $1$ to $1$. But
$$
\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}=\begin{vmatrix}e^x\cos y &- e^x\sin y\\ e^x\sin y & e^x\cos y\end{vmatrix}=e^x\ne0 \quad\forall(x,y),
$$
so that it is locally invertible.

In case you wonder how I came up with such example, $u$ and $v$ are the real and imaginary part of $e^
{x+iy}$.

Comment: I was just in the midst of typing up this same example :-)

Comment: A feeding frenzy!!

Comment: Sorry i missunterstood the question

Comment: @DominicMichaelis It happens. I do it all the time.